In an AWS Step function is there a good way to execute a subset of steps based on an input list?
I'm new to AWS Step Functions, and I'm looking to create a step function with the following functionality:
I have a lambda that takes in a JSON payload, for example
{
"ExecutionType":"A"
}

This "ExecutionType" can be either A, B, or C, and the lambda will do something different for each type. I want to input a JSON payload with a list at the start of my step function, for example [A,B], and the step function will then invoke this lambda once with the payload for ExecutionType A and once with the payload for ExecutionType B. I'm not sure how to implement this functionality though with the examples I'm seeing online.
To my understanding so far, I would want to make 3 invoke lambda states to invoke the same lambda with each different payload. But when I think about triggering these states, from looking online I only see the Choice step which, to my understanding, would only allow me to move to lambda state A, B, OR C. Meanwhile a Parallel step would require me to execute all 3.
Is the functionality I'm looking for possible in an easy way in Step Functions?

I believe you could use a map state to loop over your array of payloads to solve this. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/state-map-inline.html

This appears to be a good fit for the Map State. Below is an example.

{
  "StartAt": "Map",
  "States": {
    "Map": {
      "Type": "Map",
      "ItemProcessor": {
        "ProcessorConfig": {
          "Mode": "INLINE"
        },
        "StartAt": "Lambda Invoke",
        "States": {
          "Lambda Invoke": {
            "Type": "Task",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::lambda:invoke",
            "OutputPath": "$.Payload",
            "Parameters": {
              "FunctionName": "arn:aws:lambda:us-west-2:123456789101:function:myFunctionName",
              "Payload": {
                "ExecutionType.$": "$"
              }
            },
            "Retry": [
              {
                "ErrorEquals": [
                  "States.ALL"
                ],
                "IntervalSeconds": 1,
                "MaxAttempts": 3,
                "BackoffRate": 2
              }
            ],
            "End": true
          }
        }
      },
      "End": true,
      "ItemsPath": "$.executionTypes"
    }
  }
}

